# Trying to add to front in a singly linked list but new node and head are overwriting each other

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, nodes, singly-linked-list

I am writing a linked list class, node, stack, and queue class in c++ for class, but I am new to the language and the pointers keep overwriting each other. Here is the beginning of my linked list class and the problem method, as well as the Node class:

```
class SinglyLinkedList
{
public:
    Node* head;
    Node* tail;

    // default constructor
    SinglyLinkedList()
    {
        head = NULL;
        tail = NULL;
    }

    // add front
    void addFront(Node* n)
    {
        // front is empty - first value
        if (head == NULL)
        {
            head = n;
            tail = n;
        }
        else // FIX THIS
        {
            n->pointer = head;
            head = n;
        }
    }
    ...
}

class Node
{
public:
    char value;
    Node* pointer;
};
```

I've tried messing with dereferencing and the address of operator but nothing I try has worked and I'm just getting more and more confused.

Comment: Show a minimal complete program that appends nodes to the beginning of the list.

Comment: That looks fine, what is the problem you're having? Is it the two assignments `n->pointer = head` and `head = n` that confuses you? Something else?

Comment: One of the methods that never work is inserting `*` and `&` in the hopes of stumbling on a correct combination.

Comment: Please read about the [mcve] and post a complete program that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: side note: use `nullptr` instead of `NULL`

Comment: @OrenIshShalom You are absolutely right. I have edited my answer below accordingly.

Comment: It works fine [here](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b441ee5accbb49ba). I *suspect* that you're adding `Node*`s you acquire with `&` and either reuse the same `Node`, or use `Node`s whose lifetimes have ended when you examine the list contents. But it's very difficult to say for sure without a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

In `addFront()`, if the list is empty the new node pointer does not get set.

While fixing this, the logic can be simplified as follows:

```
    void addFront(Node* n)
    {
        if (head == nullptr)
        {   // front is empty - first value
            tail = n;
        }
        n->pointer = head;  // Point to the previous front or NULL if the list was empty before
        head = n;           // Point to the new front
    }
```

**Edit**: Changed `NULL` to C++-style `nullptr`. This should also be done in the constructor. Thanks to comment by @OrenIshShalom.

Comment: This answer looks good to me, but it is strange that the comments in the original code indicate that a different fix is needed.

Comment: "If the head is null, then set the tail"? That feels a little odd to me. Why not check the tail instead?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Could do, but it is a matter of taste since the checks are equivalent so I kept the OP original style. If the list is empty, then both `head` and `tail` are both `nullptr`. If the list is not empty, then they are both different from `nullptr`. In other words: it is only if the list is empty that inserting at the front changes the tail.

Comment: thanks but i figured it out! still not sure exactly what was going on with the pointers that was causing the new node to overwrite the old head node, but i just created the new node instance inside of the addFront function and it resolved the pointer issues. Like i said im new to the language, but its probably related to the fact that i was passing a pointer into the function.

Comment: @geejers Good you got it solved. In principle, there is no problem in passing a Node pointer to the function, so that would not be the problem, but since you did not include this part of the code, it is hard to comment on that. See the comment by  
molbdnilo above, though.